# Макрос для удаления мусора из HTML-тегов, но оставить нужное

Tags: макрос

Помогите, пожалуйста, написать макрос по очистке тегов.
Необходимо очистить спарсенные описания от лишнего "мусора" в тегах.

Есть макрос, который удаляет все атрибуты в тегах:

```
Sub ЧисткаHTML()    
    Dim cell As Range

    For Each cell In ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns(1).Cells        
cell = HTML_DeleteAttributes(cell)

    Next cell

End Sub

Function HTML_DeleteAttributes(ByVal txt$)

    On Error Resume Next
    With CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
        .Global = True
        .Pattern = "(<[A-Za-z1-6]+)[^<>]*(>)"
        txt$ = .Replace(txt$, "$1$2")
        .Pattern = ">\s*<"
        txt$ = .Replace(txt$, "><")
    End With
    HTML_DeleteAttributes = txt$
End Function
```

Макрос отличный, все теги очищает на ура! Но в моем случае есть один ньюанс. В тегах td возможны значения rowspan и colspan. Их необходимо оставлять при очистке.

Например, из этого тега

```
<td rowspan=2 style=width:115.55pt,border:solid windowtext 1.0pt, mso-border-alt:solid windowtext .5pt,padding:0cm 5.4pt 0cm 5.4pt width=154 valign=top>
```

при очистке должно замениться на `<td rowspan=2>`

Причем варианты возможны такие:

```
1. <td ...простой мусор, без rowspan и colspan> 
2. <td ...colspan=...> - только colspan
3. <td ...rowspan=...> - только rowspan
4. <td ..colspan=4...rowspan=5...> - присутствует и rowspan и colspan.
```

Значение colspan и rowspan может быть любым числом от 2 до 13 (в моем случае).
Таких позиций у меня порядка 10 тыс штук, вручную все проверить нереально.
Прошу помощи в написании или редактировании этого макроса. 
Спасибо!

Comment: Может, перед созданием вопроса стоило сначала проверить то, что Вам дали, и ответить там? https://www.planetaexcel.ru/forum/index.php?PAGE_NAME=read&FID=1&TID=104934&TITLE_SEO=104934-udalit-musor-ikh-htmltegov-no-ostavit-nuzhnoe

Comment: в первом варианте там необходимо дописать макрос - я этого делать не умею к сожалению. А во втором случае - результат оставляет только теги td, удаляя все остальное.

Comment: А проявить уважение к помогающим и отреагировать на предложенную помощь - это выше Вашего достоинства?

Comment: Да и относительно *stakoverflow*: здесь нужно было показать имеющиеся варианты и объяснить, почему не подходят. Иначе Вам могут предлагать похожее, тратить на это время, не зная, что такие варианты уже есть.

Comment: vikttur, хорошее замечание, я Вас понял. В будущем внимательнее буду.

Comment: Помощь оказал tolstak, написал вариант паттерна для RegExp:
(<(?:td|tr))[^>]*?((?: colspan| rowspan)\s*=\s*\S+)?[^>]*?((?: colspan| rowspan)\s*=\s*\S+)?[^>]*?(>)

файл можно скачать тут: https://www.planetaexcel.ru/forum/index.php?PAGE_NAME=message&FID=1&TID=104934&TITLE_SEO=104934-udalit-musor-ikh-htmltegov-no-ostavit-nuzhnoe
не найду как ту его прикрепить. Всем спасибо!